# No me reconoce variable POST

Tags: php

Estoy probando con POSTMAN mi codigo PHP de index.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'controllers/loginController.php';

$usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];

$login=new LoginController();
$array=$login->crearToken($usuario,$contraseña);

?>
```

El caso es que me dice:
**Notice:  Undefined index: usuario in **C:\laragon\www\APIVENTAS\index.php** on line **4****

Estoy poniendo como metodo "POST" en postman y pasandole los dos parametros en la pestaña Params.

En logincontroller.php tengo (lo dejo por las dudas):

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/claseConexion.php';
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

class LoginController{
    
    public function __construct(){
       

        }
       
    public function existeUsuario($nombreusuario,$contraseña){
     
           
            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $nombreusuario) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $contraseña)){
        
                try
                {
                    $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
                    
                    $sqluser="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre AND pass = :pass;";
                 
                  $sql=$conexion->prepare($sqluser);
                  $sql->bindParam(":nombre",$nombreusuario,PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
                  $sql->bindParam(":pass",$contraseña,PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
           
                  $sql->execute();
                 
                   $array=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
              
                    return $array;
                 
                          
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
          
        
        
    }
    public function crearToken($nombreusuario,$contraseña){
        $usuario=this.existeUsuario($nombreusuario,$contraseña);
            if (count($usuario)>0){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $nombre = $row['user'];
            
                $secret_key = "OLAh6Yh5KwNFvOqgltw7";
                $issuer_claim = "localhost";
                $audience_claim = "THE_AUDIENCE";
                $issuedat_claim = time(); 
            
                $notbefore_claim = $issuedat_claim + 10; //not before in seconds
                $expire_claim = $issuedat_claim + 60; // expire time in seconds
                $token = array(
                    "iss" => $issuer_claim,
                    "aud" => $audience_claim,
                    "iat" => $issuedat_claim,
                    "nbf" => $notbefore_claim,
                    "exp" => $expire_claim,
                    "data" => array(
                       
                        "firstname" => $nombre,
                       
                ));

                http_response_code(200);

                $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $secret_key);
                echo json_encode(
                    array(
                        "message" => "Logueado satisfactoriamente",
                        "jwt" => $jwt,
                   
                        "expireAt" => $expire_claim
                    ));
                }
                    else{

                    http_response_code(401);
                    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Login failed.", "password" => $password));
                    }

        
                }       
}
?>
```

como veran la idea es obtener user y pass y generar un token.

Comment: Si te la esta reconociendo lo que no reconoce es el indice **usuario** y **contraseña**

Comment: Claro pero en POSTMAN si paso dos parámetros : usuario y contraseña con sus respectivos valores

Comment: entonces no es culpa de tu backend...

Comment: Lo que sea con Postman no lo estás haciendo bien, o no como crees. Quizá envías por POST pero los parámetros los pasas por GET. Puedes probar a usar $_REQUEST en vez de $_POST en tu script a ver qué pasa.

Comment: Definitivamente estaba pasando mal los parámetros. Estaba usando la pestaña Params en vez de body.